# Environment 'lstlisting' inserts spaces in pdf

Tags: pdf, latex, lstlisting

When I write

```
\begin{lstlisting}
    /opt/httpServer/lighttpd/config/lighttpd.conf
\end{lstlisting}
```

and view the line in my PDF document, copy and paste it to an editor, I receive

```
/ opt / h t t p S e r v e r / l i g h t t p d / c o n f i g / l i g h t t p d . c o n f
```

Does anyone know the reason for this and maybe even a solution?

Comment: Are you using evince? Maybe related  https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/issues/1553#note_1048627

Comment: I am using zathura, but I get the same results for okular and evince

Comment: These are all Poppler based viewers, aren't they?

Comment: You are absolutely right, they are. Thanks for pointing that out! So I guess I'll have to wait until this bug is fixed? The document I want to write will be a manual, and if you cannot copy the code parts because the format is buggy, the whole thing kind of becomes obsolete...

Comment: copying code from a pdf is always hit and miss and there will always be some pdf viewer in which it does not work. If it is important that readers can get the exact same text, have a look at `attachfile2` and similar packages.